# Only one additional @user can be notified...

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, comment, comment-replies

I wanted to give the *update part* of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162117/kx-s-cong-kfx-s), as a comment. It is impossible, and I see the following: 
"Only one additional @user can be notified..."
So I add that comment as the *update part* within the question. Now I don't need to give the comment. But I think it is a bug and can be corrected.

Comment: Did you want to post this:` $\require{AMScd}$

\begin{CD}
  0 @>>>     S @>\alpha>>       S^2 @>\beta>>    S @>>>0\\
    @.      @V id V V   @VV id V     @VV id V           \\
  0 @>>>     S @>\gamma>>       S^2 @>\theta>>    S @>>>0
\end{CD}

Comment: Yes, and u fix it by a "`"? Still i believe  it's better the bug to be corrected.

Comment: It's not really a bug. It is just  that the test for a feature is "stupid" and catches this as false positive. I doubt it's worth it to try to make the tes smarter. The backtick-exception is there for such cases and works well enough. Anyway the content was better as edit than as comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly certain I understand what is your concern, but I believe I finally understood what it might be.

It is *by design* that only one user can be @-notified per comment. If you want to change this, I doubt this will happen.

However, it seems this is not your actual concern. Rather it is that you wanted to submit a comment containing something like:

```
\begin{CD}
  0 @>>>     S @>\alpha>>       S^2 @>\beta>>    S @>>>0\\
@.      @V id V V   @VV id V     @VV id V           \\
  0 @>>>     S @>\gamma>>       S^2 @>\theta>>    S @>>>0
\end{CD}
```

Due to the many @ this triggers the test for multiple notifications, and blocks submission of the comment. Granted this test is apparently implemented in a simplistic way (just checking for @).

However,  there is a dedicated feature to side-step the test namely inserting a backtick (`) somewhere in the comment. Doing this you could submit your comment just fine.

I feel this is sufficient and would not consider making that test smarter a particular concern.